# Como fazer o teste unitário na class validator em um form do Laravel?

Tags: validação, laravel-5.3, testes-de-unidade

Um bom dia senhores.

Sou um estudante de programação, nesse momento estou estudando como efetuar testes unitários usando o Laravel 5.3

Em meus testes me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Meu pequeno sistema apenas visa cadastrar produtos em uma base de dados.
Após a inserção dos dados nos formularios envio para minha função store do meu controle onde faço minhas validações:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'nome' => 'bail|required|unique:produtos|min:2',
        'valor' => 'bail|required|min:0.1|numeric|'
    ]);
    Produto::create($request->all());
    return redirect('produtos');
}
```

Gostaria de fazer testes que capturem se essas validates estão realmente funcionando, porem não estou conseguindo realizar tal procedimento.

Segue o codigo:

```
class ProdutoTest extends TestCase
{

use DatabaseTransactions;
public function testExample()
{

    $this->visit('produtos/create')
         ->type("a", 'nome')
         ->type(15, 'valor')
         ->press('Cadastrar')
         ->seePageIs('produtos/create');



    Produto::create([
        'nome' => '45',
        'valor' => '77'
    ])  ;
}

}
```

Pelo oque pude entender nesse teste estou apenas testando meu formulario, e a criação de dados informados diretamente na base de dados.

Como faço para testar minhas validates ?

PS:"Os nomes e organização do código de teste estão bem sem noção, visto que ainda não ajeitei haha..."

Answer (score 0):

Galera pesquisando na internet acredito ter encontrado uma solução satisfátoria

Segue o Código:

```
public function testNomeComUmCaracter()
{

    $this->visit('produtos/create')
         ->type('h', 'nome')
         ->type(15, 'valor')
         ->press('Cadastrar')
         ->notSeeInDatabase('produtos', ['nome' => 'h'])
         ->seePageIs('produtos/create');
}
```

Nesse teste simulei uma tentativa de cadastro colocando um nome com apenas 1 carácter, em nosso exemplo "h", tal inserção irá de encontro com minhas validates:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'nome' => 'bail|required|unique:produtos|min:2',
    'valor' => 'bail|required|min:0.1|numeric|'
]);
Produto::create($request->all());
return redirect('produtos');
}
```

Logo uso o comando:`notSeeInDatabase`
Com isso estou tentando visualisar se os dados não estou contidos em meu BD, oque significa que minhas validates mataram a tentantiva de insert

Por fim utilizo o comando:`use DatabaseTransactions`
Oque fará com que meu banco não seja populado de verdade, já que o teste dispara contra o banco de dados para o teste, e posteriormente realiza um Rollback, não deixando rastros tão pouco gastando meus IDs.